# Find the smallest non-negative integer not contained in a binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, binary-tree

the method return the smallest non-negative integer number that is not contains in the binary tree.

Example:

with 0 1 2 3 return 4.

with 1 2 3 4 return 0.

with 0 1 2 5 6 return 3.

with 6 1 5 2 return 3.

Complexity of my solution is O(n^2). How I can resolve in a time no more than O(n)?

```
public static <E> int minIntNotContains(BinTree<Nodo<Integer>> node) {
    List<Integer> a=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int min=minIntNotContainsRic(node,a);
    return min;
}

public static <E> int minIntNotContainsRic(BinTree<Nodo<Integer>> node,List<Integer> a) {
    int min= node.getValue().getValue();
    a.add(node.getValue().getValue());
    if(node.getLeftSubtree() != null) {
        min = Math.min(min, minIntNotContainsRic(node.getLeftSubtree(),a));
    }
    if(node.getRightSubtree() != null) {
        min = Math.min(min, minIntNotContainsRic(node.getRightSubtree(),a));
    }
    if (min>0) return 0;  
    else{
        for (int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
            if (!a.contains(i+1)){
                return i+1;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }           
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't `1 2 5 6` return 0?

Comment: How do you know this is O(n^2)? Why do you need to loop over the list in each recursive call?

Comment: sorry is the smallest non-negative integer.

Comment: Is it a special binary tree, such as a search tree? Or just any binary tree?

Comment: List.contains() method cost O(n), which is a way more efficient to solve the problem?

Comment: It is a simple binary tree, is not a BST

Comment: 0 *is* non-negative. And if you mean positive, why does `1 2 3 4` return 0? And if 0 means "no missing integers", why does `0 1 2 3` return 4?

Comment: This question is not well defined. There is so much information missing, which could help. Is the tree a balanced search tree? No... well; it's just some array then from a complexity-standpoint. You got upper/lower bounds on the values? ... Well...if there is no ordering in the tree, the only solution is just a traverse-iteration to grab all values and hold the min/max (whatever you need). That's O(n) and is the lower bound.

Comment: 0 <= result <=Integer.MAX_VALUE. If the nodes are 1234 the the smallest non-negative integer is 0.

Comment: is a generic tree, there are no conditions. The real text of exercise is: Write an algorithm (Java code) that, given a binary tree whose nodes contain non-negative integers, determine in time / linear space the smallest non-negative integer that is not contained in the tree and return it.

Comment: Then the answer is **theta(N) for space and time complexity** as you always need to traverse the full tree, because there is no inference possible about lower-levels (you don't know anything about the values at lower levels or about any part of the tree)

Comment: exactly, then I would understand how to solve the exercise in O(n).

Comment: @MrEnrich Just implement some traversal and keep only the information about the *until now observed min-value*. [wiki on tree-traversal incl. pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

Comment: @sascha: while you might be on the right track, please sketch what information to keep and how to use it: with four numbers, how does `Just … keep … min-value` help if after 2 0 3 the last one is a) 1 b) 4 or c) 5?

Comment: Why doesn't 1 2 5 6 return 0?  Return 0, I was wrong to write

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to calculate the number of elements in the tree in O(n) by walking the tree.  Call this value `x`.

Populate a boolean array of size `x` with true if the index value appears in the tree, false otherwise (ie `bool[y] == true` iff `y` appears in the tree) by walking the tree.  Ignore all values `y` in the tree where `y < 0` or `y >= x`.

The smallest non-negative integer not present in the tree is either the index of the first element of the boolean array that is false, or `x` if all elements are true.

To put this another way, for any container of size `x`, either:

1. One of the numbers `0..x-1` is not contained in the tree; or
2. All of the numbers `0..x-1` are contained in the tree, in which case the smallest non-negative number not contained in the tree is `x`.

Comment: That's a lot of unnecessary work (again: one traversal is enough to collect the lowest non-negative number). i'm also puzzled by the approach: ```if the index value appears in the tree```? Does that mean, that you need a boolean-array of size = max(value-in-tree)? This will blow up the memory if a 1e10 value is existent.

Comment: The array only needs to be the same size as the number of elements in the tree, consistent with O(n) space requirement in comments. Would be interested to see how to do this in one pass.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the binary tree follows that all left children are smaller than their parents and all right children are larger than their parent, you could use this property of the tree to reduce the amount you need to search through.

Edit: Since your tree is generic my immediate idea would be to perform an O(n) sort, perhaps counting sort. Then iterate through to find the smallest int that is missing. Total complexity O(2n)

Comment: Why sorting if updating the current candidate value is enough? That's a lot of unnecessary work!